# Removing content of a TableData

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I'd like to remove the `<tbody>` content of a datatable how this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field_1</th>
            <th>Field_2</th>
            <th>Field_3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTableBody">
        <tr>
            <td>DATA</td>
            <td>DATA</td>
            <td>DATA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DATA</td>
            <td>DATA</td>
            <td>DATA</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I tried with `$("#myTableBody").empty()` or `$("#myTableBody").html("")` but it doesn't work. I don't want remove the `<thead>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: your code is working see here http://jsfiddle.net/apg8vevc/2/

Comment: first include the jquery library your code is working fine \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your code is working [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/apg8vevc/2/) ,you can try below answers :

Try

```
$("#myTableBody tr").empty()
```

OR

```
$("#myTableBody tr").html("")
```

OR

```
$("#myTable tbody tr").empty()
```

OR

```
$("#myTable tbody").empty()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/apg8vevc/)

**Don't forget to include jquery library and put jquery code inside `document.ready()` block.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/s8pqqnL9/1/

```
$("#myTable tbody").html("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a datatable, you have to use the datatable API to create or remove rows.

To clear all the rows in your table :

```
// using datatable 1.9 or lower :
$('#myTable').dataTable().fnClearTable();

// using datatables 1.10 or higher :
$('#myTable').dataTable().clear();
```

Reference :

- [for v1.9](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnClearTable)
- [for v1.10](http://datatables.net/reference/api/clear())